# WebClient unable to download file when run as Local System

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webclient

I have a windows service running as the default Local System (on Windows Server 2008 R2) that attempts to pull down a PDF from a user-provided URL.  If that URL is in the local intranet there's a happy ending.  If the URL points to a more remote URL (say from irs.gov), I get an exception:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ...

If I change the the "Logon as" account from Local System to my account (for instance), the request goes through.  But I'm reluctant to run a windows service as a real user (am I being too conservative?).

The code I'm using seems pretty simple:

```
string destinationFileName = ...;
Uri uri = ...;
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.DownloadFile(uri.AbsoluteUri, destinationFileName );
}
```

Do I need to get some kind of IE settings and add them to the WebClient instance?  If so, what?

Thanks for any hints or pointers!

Comment: Sounds to me like the proxy server isn't set... Netsh?

Comment: I think the proxy server is set.  if I use netsh in the winhttp context and ask "show proxy", I get the expected settings.  Are separate settings kept for Local System?  If so, how do I specify that user?

Comment: Local System passes the computer account credentials to network resources. If your corporate proxy uses windows authentication, chances are the systems administrators allow access for users but not computers.

Comment: @Russ does this connection use the machine/user account as a credential? I.e. is this using windows authentication? If so, I know **exactly** what is wrong (and how to fix it)

Comment: Not sure how to handle this as far as stackoverflow credit goes, but Marc Gravell had the right idea.

The user account I was logged in as did have a proxy defined, but the Local System user didn't.  When I programmatically defined a proxy all was well.As far as credentials go... I'll look into that too for completeness (I suspect it will eventually cause me problems, even though I seem to be good now).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Russ how did you solve this issue?

Comment: @MarcGravell i got the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776256/system-net-sockets-socketexception-0x80004005-while-downloading-a-file-from-wi

Answer (score 1):

Try running your service with NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. If that doesn't do the trick, Create a user account with appropriately restricted rights and run your service with that account.

Also, if you're running on Windows Server 2008 R2 give the [Managed Service Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff641731%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) topic on Technet a look.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>LocalSystem doesn't have access to network resources.  Use `NETWORK SERVICE` account.</strike>

EDIT:
LocalSystem most likely does not have write permissions to the filesystem path you are using.

Comment: Says who? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It has anonymous access; it just can't authenticate as the machine

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  I've run into this in the past when trying to access network shares.  Mind jumped to no access.. but it was no auth to the network share.  My mistake.

Comment: Says who?! Read the documentation, both of you. It authenticates with the computer credentials *The service presents the computer's credentials to remote servers.* and has pretty much full access to everything on the machine *Its token includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs; these accounts have access to most system objects*

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I believe Marc was refering to LocalService account.  Easy enough to get confused in this context.

Comment: @Boo Not really, one's all powerful and the other one's not.