# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005) while downloading a file from windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, socketexception, webclient

While downloading a file, I got:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005).

I have a C# service application. While trying to download the file, one of my clients got the following exception.

#### Code

```
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                client.DownloadFile(url, name);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error inside DownloadFile");
            Logger.Error(e.message);
            Logger.Error(e.InnerException);
        }
```

**Exception**

> Error inside DownloadFile
> Œﬁ∑®¡¨Ω”µΩ‘∂≥Ã∑˛ŒÒ∆˜
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): ”…”⁄ƒø±Íº∆À„ª˙ª˝º´æ‹æ¯£¨Œﬁ∑®¡¨Ω”°£ 108.160.165.189:443
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

From the browser, a user can download a file. But from a service application the issue occurs. The service is running as the system user.

Comment: At a glance, this looks like corrupt memory.

Comment: @CodeCaster what that means? i don't understand

Comment: Given the unintelligible exception message and the generic unspecified error (0x80004005), it would look like the machine that ran this code has faulty memory. If it's a one-off error on many runs, I wouldn't investigate it any further, or suggest they run a MemTest.

Comment: Likewise, if the amount of sockets that can be provisioned is exceeded by this request, that could also cause the error, but it is very generic. Gather more information using the Socket Exception class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketexception?view=net-5.0) and research more from that specific exception (not the generic)